# C# windows service identify which function key is pressed

Tags: c#, windows

I am creating a windows service, in this service, I want to detect when a specific key is pressed. I have checked following 
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/toub/2006/05/03/low-level-keyboard-hook-in-c/

This solution seems to capture all keys but the function keys..The problem here is most likely my lack of understanding. Can some one please guide me here how to modify code in the example above so that I can handle when any of the function keys are pressed (From F1 to F12).
Thanks in advance

Comment: You might want to take a look at the list of virtual keycodes on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes as the F1-F12 keys have their own keycode. You could match these in the hook function

Comment: It seems like HookCallback is not even called (tested with printline statement). If it did then I could have tested for a specific key.

Comment: I am referring to FI-F12 keys, HookCallback doesnt seem to be called for special keys for regular keys of keyboard it works perfectly. And I am looking for to identify which F1-F12 key is pressed

Answer (score 0):

The link posted in my question has the solution which works correctly. My issue was my own code where it was preventing the code to work..There is a bit Application.Run() in the code that I had commented out and it was causing issue..Apologies for wasting space...